# Software rendering versus hardware rendering for am image viewer?

Tags: sdl, sfml

I am going to make a lightweight, fast image viewer. I am curious as to which would be better for this project. SFML (using opengl) or SDL (using software rendering). My assumption is hardware rendering with opengl should be faster. Is this right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, as opposed to SDL. Though software rendering is usually faster, SDL is very high level and therefore slower. Downvote me if you want, but this is the truth. May I ask why you can't just use the operating system's API? Image controls are very versatile.

Comment: I hope to learn a multimedia API. However, I think the imagemagick api may be faster for this project as it seems lower level. I am not sure which system apis linux has for displaying images.

Comment: That's a good point. It's some X11 something. You should look into GTK+  -I think that might be it.